# Rails- How would I set a flag or indicator once a specific action is complete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a specific flow of actions in my application and I'm at a point where I want a user to fill out three separate forms with different information on them (they all are part of the Questionnaire model kinda), then I want it to display different information on their dashboard once all three are filled out. I thought of a couple solutions, but I'm not sure which is best:

- Do something in jQuery (always feels kinda hacky when I do things in jQuery like this though)
- Set up three different models for these three forms and write a method like once_prereqs_are_complete (Leaning towards this method)
- Last idea: Make attributes of that model and write a method that makes sure all of the information in those forms are filled out (`@questionnaire.name && @questionnaire.title`)

Is there an easier way to do what I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a three screens "wizard" to guide the user. Serialize the information between screens and at the end save all the info into the Model:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

Maybe wicked can be useful:

https://github.com/schneems/wicked

Comment: Thanks for that, I would've never found that gem. I'll take a look and see if either of those cases will do the job!

Comment: As an update, @aarkerio that gem was exactly what I was looking for and helped facilitate my project well with a little modification!